# Div keeps overflowing onto other elements when zoomed in

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to make a small web page with a search bar and an accounts menu (currently just a circle), but I've noticed, when I zoom in, or resize the page, the accounts menu overflows onto the search bar. I've tried changing from absolute positioning, to relative and adjusting the `right: 30px` accordingly, but this didn't work. I'm incredibly stuck, can anyone offer any advice/code?

```css
body {
  font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.search-btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #009AFF;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 11px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.search {
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 15px;
}
.logo a {
  color: #009AFF;
  font-size: 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
  width: 200px;
}
.content {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  top: 65px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#account-items {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 72px;
  padding: 5px;
}
/*.accounts:hover #account-items {
  display: inline;
}*/
#account-items a {
  color: #009AFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#account-items a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.accounts {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  top: 4px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.accounts .image {
  background-image: url("/email/scripts/profile.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 63px;
  height: 63px;
}
a {
  color: #009AFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.js-is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <center><a href="#">Unnamed</a></center>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
        <form action="search.php" method="GET">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="input" autocomplete="off" />
          <button type="submit" class="search-btn">Go</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="accounts">
        <div class="image">
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the absolute positioning and stick with the default relative, then use a display of `inline-block` (Read up on what it does here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) and use dynamic widths instead of static ones, you should get your desired result.

See the updated code below;

```css
body {
  font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.search-btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #009AFF;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input {
  width: calc(100% - 100px); /* CHANGED */
  padding: 11px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.search {
  max-width: 600px; /* CHANGED */
  width: calc(100% - 300px); /* ADDED */
  /* position: absolute; REMOVED */
  /* left: 200px; REMOVED */
  /*top: 15px; REMOVED */
  display: inline-block; /* ADDED */
  vertical-align: middle; /* ADDED */
}
.logo a {
  color: #009AFF;
  font-size: 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
  /*position: absolute; //REMOVED */
  /*left: 0; //REMOVED */
  display: inline-block; /* ADDED */
  vertical-align: middle; /* ADDED */
  top: 12px;
  width: 200px;
}
.content {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  top: 65px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#account-items {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 72px;
  padding: 5px;
}
/*.accounts:hover #account-items {
  display: inline;
}*/
#account-items a {
  color: #009AFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#account-items a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.accounts {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* position: absolute; REMOVED */
  /* right: 30px; REMOVED */
  width: calc(100% - 809px); /* CHANGED */
  height: 66px;
  /* top: 4px; REMOVED */
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block; /* ADDED */
  vertical-align: middle; /* ADDED */
  text-align: right; /* ADDED */
}
.accounts .image {
  background-image: url("/email/scripts/profile.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 63px;
  height: 63px;
  display: inline-block; /* ADDED */
}
a {
  color: #009AFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.js-is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <center><a href="#">Unnamed</a></center>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
        <form action="search.php" method="GET">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="input" autocomplete="off" />
          <button type="submit" class="search-btn">Go</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="accounts">
        <div class="image">
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.header {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 900px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/59ncte3m/1/

It will avoid the issue where your menu gets drawn on top of the search by making the header a positioned element, the menu absolute position will be relative to the header. giving it a min-width will make sure all elements fit within.

This is still not a good responsive design, as it should avoid pixel dimentions, but it is enough to fix the overflowing issue.